# All custom defined variables mssing in test from process.env

Tags: node.js, jestjs, dotenv

The `dotenv 8.2` is installed in my `nodejs 12.15` app. The`.env` file is located under `app_root/config/` and `dotenv` is required in app's `index.js` file:

```
require("dotenv").config(path: __dirname+"/config/.env");
```

The app runs fine with "node index.js" at the app's root subdirectory. However when testing with `jest 25.0` under the app root `npm test`, the db connection throws error because it calls `process.env.DB_PASSWORD` for the db password and returns nothing. When console.log `process.env` in test environment, I notice the custom defined variables are completely missing. How to bring back all custom defined variables missing in test environment?

Comment: Is your `index.js` imported/required from your test code?

Comment: no, Here is the `test` script in `package.json`:     "scripts": {
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --testTimeout=10000 --watchAll --verbose"
  },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like when Jest is running, it doesn't include your `index.js`, where `dotenv` variables is required.

There are few options to run jest with .env variables:

```
// npm run script
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --setupFiles dotenv/config"
  }
}

// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  setupFiles: ["dotenv/config"],
}

// jest in package.json
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": ["dotenv/config"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works as well. Create a jest.config.js in app's root directory:

```
require('dotenv').config({path: process.cwd() +'/config/.env'});

module.exports = {
    verbose:true,
    testTimeout:10000
}
```

And add the scripts in package.json:

```
"test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --config=./jest.config.js --watchAll"
```